# How do I deal with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" on a physical phone?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm getting what seems to be a common error. `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"` when I try to retrieve the contents of a website on a physical phone (in this case an Android phone).

I've experienced something similar with `ionic server` where it was getting CORS errors, and resolved it by using proxies in the `ionic.config.json` file. But I understand I shouldn't have that issue on a physical device.

```
// searchString = "https://swapi.co/api/films";
searchString = "https://www.example.com";

console.log(searchString);

self.httpClient.get(searchString, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
  (data: string) => {
    console.log("my data: " + data + " " + searchString);
  },
  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log("my err: " + error.message);
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

When I run it on the phone, if I use https://swapi.co the code returns the web page I expect.

If I use https://www.example.com, I get the following error in the phone's console.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1
my err: Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error 4.js:238
  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false…}
    error: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent
    headers: HttpHeaders
    message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 0
    statusText: "Unknown Error"
    url: null
    __proto__: __
```

The "right" solution seems to be to add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to https://www.example.com (which is probably what the owner of http://swapie.co did); however, I don't control that server so I can't.

How can I convince `httpClient` not to expect these headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. CORS is there to prevent what you're trying to do, block cross origin requests for unapproved origins.  Best you can try to do is lie about your host but you'll have to throw out your http client and write your own. but IOS or android may have seen you coming and taken measures to prevent such things.

Comment: So you are saying that CORS impacts both ionic serve and physical devices? Why am I seeing lots of posts around say "this won't be a problem on the phone/device"?

Comment: CORS is designed to provide some level of security for users and webservers, so your theoretical phone app can't download a web page from example.com, inject scripts into it to steal user data, and then pass itself off as example.com.  CORS is definitely a problem for phones, but it's becoming common practice to just allow all origins because CORS isn't the most secure thing and is a bit outdated for the modern web. Typically REST APIs will allow all origins since CORS doesn't provide any security for an API.  but CORS is still important for actual web pages.

Comment: So, what's happened, near as I can figure out from my googling, is that at some point it it did work, and that "hole" was closed (probably circa Cordova version 5), and the examples I was seen must have predated that. And the only ways forward are to 1) go to the native http plugin 2) fix the server 3) set up some other proxy server off the phone somewhere.

Comment: sounds about right. If you're trying to display web pages to users, which is a common application activity, you can just use the in app browser cordova supplies and then you won't have cors issues.